# QPX express API is returning error 403

Tags: json, android-pay

Guys I'm using the google console to test qpx express api and i constantly get back this 403 error.

```
403 Forbidden

- Hide headers -

cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  260
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Mon, 30 Mar 2015 08:42:13 GMT
expires:  Mon, 30 Mar 2015 08:42:13 GMT
server:  GSE
vary:  Origin, X-Origin

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (QPX Express API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (QPX Express API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
 }
}
```

my request is this...

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "request": {
  "passengers": {
   "adultCount": 1
  },
  "slice": [
   {
    "destination": "LCY",
    "origin": "ATH",
    "date": "2015-08-27"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

as defined by the qpx doc...
my project has the qpx api enabled.What am i missing here..????

Comment: made the same rquest..and the reply is again the same but error code says

Comment: 403 OK to the above request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.
The problem was tha I used android key instead of a Browser key that was required fro my application.
That is why qpx api was blocking my request.
STEPS.
Inside APIs & auth ---> credentials 
created a browser key and left referers blank so it is by default set to any refers allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The message is quite clear, the reason is indicated: `accessNotConfigured`. 
Please, review again your API enabled:

- from Google Developer Console, choose your Project.
- choose API & Auth/APIs option
- select the tab "Enabled APIs"
- check QPX Express Airfare API and enable it

Comment: I did this already and still getting that error.qpx is enabled for my project.